# Awful Looking Dendrogram Cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, but my dendrogram keeps being generated like the image below. I have 600 documents that I created a non-sparse document-term matrix for. How can I correctly format the dendrogram?

```
library(cluster)
uni.dist <- dist(t(unigram.dtm.nonsparse), method='euclidean')
uni.fit <- hclust(d=uni.dist, method='ward.D2')
plot(uni.fit, hang=-1)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

Comment: Do you want to cluster documents, or terms? If documents, then don't transpose `unigram.dtm.nonsparse`. If terms, then your dendrogram may very well be a mess because there will be a very high number of terms.

Comment: Note also that if your terms are counts, then Euclidean distance will be affected by variations in document length. Alternatives would be normalisation (on term frequency) or using an alternative distance metric such as cosine distance.

Comment: Those both make a lot of sense. Thank you.